# Install CentOS on SCSI hard drive under Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, centos, virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

How can I install Centos 6 on SCSI hard drive under Hyper-V? I added a IDE drive to boot from but CentOS doesn't recognize SCSI drive during install. How can I fix this please?

Comment: Just curious, any reason it has to be a SCSI drive?

Comment: Sure: http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=9129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Linux Integration Services for Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34603) is the solution. Last version is really easy to install and there is only one problem, After upgrading Linux Kernel OS will crash while booting. to fix this you can switch back to older kernel in grub listings.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need the Hyper-V paravirtualized drivers installed to see the SCSI drive.